# Angular - Smart table won't fill

Tags: angular, angular6, smart-table, ng2-smart-table

My Smart table won't fill using HttpClient to send a get request to get json data.

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:56591/api/db/get').subscribe((data) => {
  return data;
});
```

This returns:

```
[
  {"id":1,"name":"User1","email":"user1@email.com","password":"test"},
  {"id":2,"name":"User2","email":"user@email.com","password":"test"},
  {"id":3,"name":"User3","email":"user@email.com","password":"test"}
]
```

Using the return in subscribe gives me this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
>       at LocalDataSource.push../node_modules/ng2-smart-table/lib/data-source/local/local.data-source.js.LocalDataSource.getElements
>   (local.data-source.js:71)

While assigning the object directly to a variable is working:

```
var data = [
  {"id":1,"name":"User1","email":"user1@email.com","password":"test"},
  {"id":2,"name":"User2","email":"user@email.com","password":"test"},
  {"id":3,"name":"User3","email":"user@email.com","password":"test"}
];
return data;
```

The only difference I can find is that this code gives an error when using the get request instead of directly assigning a variable to the object..

```
constructor(private service: SmartTableService) {
  const data = this.service.getData();
  this.source.load(data);
}
```

> Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.

Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the Http request to complete before you can assign the data that it returns. So what is happening when you assign `const data = this.service.getData();` nothing is being returned.

You can solve this by returning an Observable from your http call in your service:

```
getData() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:56591/api/db/get');
}
```

Then in your component subscribe to the returned Observable, this will wait for the http call to resolve before passing the data into `this.source.load(data);`

```
this.service.getData().subscribe((data) => {
    this.source.load(data);
});
```

Let me know if that works, otherwise we can troubleshoot further.